# Beam GCSFileSystem/GcsBufferedWriter performance

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to download large files from http and upload those to gcs using apache-beam python sdk (2.6.0) on dataflow.

```py
from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem import GCSFileSystem

gcs = GCSFileSystem(options)
logging.info("Writing to file {}".format(filename))
f = gcs.create(filename, compression_type=CompressionTypes.UNCOMPRESSED)
chunk_size = 512 * 1024
for i, chunk in enumerate(response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size)):
    if chunk:
        f.write(chunk)
    else:
        break
    logging.info("Closing file {}".format(filename))
    f.close()
    logging.info("Closed file {}".format(filename))
```

This approach works well for small files (~kb), though I'm struggling making it work for larger size files (~Gb).

Logging indicates that it gets stuck within `f.close()`, and no file has yet been written into GCS.
I've dug into the code and it seems that GCSFileSystem instantiates a `GcsBufferedWriter` which itself writes into a multiprocessing Pipe that gets ingested by `transfer.Upload`.

I don't have much clues on what could cause this issue, I'm suspecting connections/pipes being reset or silently broken in the process (the http server I'm downloading from has very low throughput and I'm parallelizing calls with `gevent`), or simply transfer.Upload having some performance issues.

When I'm checking machine stats, I have much more incoming (20Mo/s) than out traffic (200ko/s), basically no disk writes, which makes me wonder where goes all piped data..

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I've switch to using google storage python client which indeed seems to have better performance and does work as expected.
Though I'm observing some transient errors

```
File "dataflow/make_training_chips.py", line 93, in process
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 71, in __init__
_http=_http)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 215, in __init__
_ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 169, in __init__
project = self._determine_default(project)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 182, in _determine_default
return _determine_default_project(project)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 179, in _determine_default_project
_, project = google.auth.default()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 306, in default
  raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
  DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. 
  Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials 
  and re-run the application. For more information, please see 
  https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials. 
  [while running 'ParDo(GenerateTraingChips)']
```

which happen quite often in my workers (though I retry task with exponential backoff...).